# Class declaration in puppet

Tags: puppet

I have created a module in puppet named patchmgmt and inside my init.pp file, i have defined  my class name same as my module name. Do i  need to declare my class or having the class name same as module name will do the magic.

Comment: The class name should be the same as the module name. I'm unsure if there's a further question, or if it isn't working.

Comment: Didn't answer my question. Do i need to declare my class inside init.pp

Comment: Yes, `class patchmgmt { ... }`.

Comment: Thanks Dominic, I got that. Actually i was using foreman to deploy my manifests and got to know that when using foreman, you don't need to declare class. you just need to attach the manfest to the server. It automatically declare the class.